# Apex: Find the user an event was created by

Tags: apex, event

I'm new to Apex, I'm trying to determine the ID of the User whom an event was created by in a trigger I'm making.

I can determine the ID of the Contact and the User assigned to the event:

```
String whoID = String.valueOf(Trigger.new[0].WhoId); // ID of the Contact the event is assigned to
String ownerID = String.valueOf(Trigger.new[0].OwnerId); // ID of the User assigned to the event
```

I want the ID of the user who created the event. For example, though obviously this doesn't work:

```
String createdByUserID = String.valueOf(Trigger.new[0].CreatedBy); // Doesn't work
```

There doesn't appear to be such a field for the Event object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field name is `CreatedById`.

One way to see all the field names for objects is to open the .schema file in the Force.com IDE.

**PS**

Its worth using Apex's `Id` datatype:

```
Id whoID = Trigger.new[i].WhoId;
```

rather than `String` both for code clarity and because there are some unique methods available there - see the "Id Methods" section of [Id Class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_id.htm).

Comment: Thank you. FYI I noticed `CreatedById` is only available on an after insert trigger.

Comment: @anthonygore Hadn't thought of that. I guess in a before insert `UserInfo.getUserId()` would give you the right id (usually).